# matrices forms a basis for vector space 2x2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

$\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\2&3\end{bmatrix}$
$\begin{bmatrix}3&4\\5&6\end{bmatrix}$
$\begin{bmatrix}7&8\\9&10\end{bmatrix}$
$\begin{bmatrix}11&12\\13&14\end{bmatrix}$

Show that the 4 matrix forms a basis for vector space 2x2

Comment: I have a question just like this to solve and the books example is generalized and is very vague about how to solve a specific problem. can anyone explain the whole process please?

Comment: I have a question just like this to solve and the books example is generalized and is very vague about how to solve a specific problem. but in it, it said u have to show that the trivial solution = 0 and to see if they form a basis you have to see if c1M1 +c2M2 + c3M3 + C4M4 = B, and it showed B being equal to |a,b,c,d| (2x2 matrix). but theres no c values or B so how can we apply that example? can anyone explain the whole process please?

Answer (score 10):

A *basis* for a vector space is by definition a *spanning set* which is *linearly independent*.

Here the vector space is 2x2 matrices, and we are asked to show that a collection of four specific matrices is a basis:

$$ \left\{\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\2&3\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}3&4\\5&6\end{bmatrix}, 
 \begin{bmatrix}7&8\\9&10\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}11&12\\13&14\end{bmatrix} \right\} $$

To be a spanning set means every element of the vector space can be expressed as a linear combination (of finitely many) of elements of the given set.  Here it means to show for any 2x2 matrix $\begin{bmatrix}w&x\\y&z\end{bmatrix}$ there *exist* scalar coefficients $a,b,c,d$ such that:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}w&x\\y&z\end{bmatrix} = a \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\2&3\end{bmatrix} + b \begin{bmatrix}3&4\\5&6\end{bmatrix} + c \begin{bmatrix}7&8\\9&10\end{bmatrix} + d \begin{bmatrix}11&12\\13&14\end{bmatrix} $$

To be linearly independent means that zero can be expressed as a linear combination (of finitely many) of elements of the given set *uniquely* by using zero coefficients, i.e. in the present case that:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix} = a \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\2&3\end{bmatrix} + b \begin{bmatrix}3&4\\5&6\end{bmatrix} + c \begin{bmatrix}7&8\\9&10\end{bmatrix} + d \begin{bmatrix}11&12\\13&14\end{bmatrix} $$

implies $a=b=c=d=0$.

It turns out, as Nicholas R. Peterson has already reported, that neither of these conditions is true.  The four given vectors *do not* form a basis for the vector space of 2x2 matrices.  (Some other sets of four vectors will form such a basis, but not these.)

Let's take the opportunity to explain a good way to set up the calculations, without immediately jumping to the conclusion of failure to be a basis.  The spanning set and linearly independent properties are easily combined into a method for checking if a finite set is a basis, by formulating a system of linear equations with unknown coefficients.  If the systems above (which differ only in the "given" matrix on the left hand side) are multiplied out to determine the four separate entries of the results on the right hand side, we see that the first condition (spanning) requires us to solve:

$$ 0a + 3b + 7c + 11d = w $$

$$ 1a + 4b + 8c + 12d = x $$

$$ 2a + 5b + 9c + 13d = y $$

$$ 3a + 6b + 10c + 14d = z $$

for any possible $w,x,y,z$, while the second condition (linear independence) requires us to show the homogeneous problem $w=x=y=z=0$ has a unique (trivial) solution.  Therefore treating the above linear system will tell us everything we want to know about whether the four vectors form a basis.

Presumably the Reader is familiar with solving such systems by elimination, either using the simple expedient of substitution of variables or the more systematic method of putting an augmented matrix representing the system into reduced row echelon form.  We take a middle path, of leaving the system in an equational form but performing the addition/subtraction/scaling of equations just as someone using elementary row operations might proceed.

To begin, subtract the top equation from each the three equations below it:

$$ 0a + 3b + 7c + 11d = \;w\; $$

$$ 1a + 1b + 1c + 1d = x-w $$

$$ 2a + 2b + 2c + 2d = y-w $$

$$ 3a + 3b + 3c + 3d = z-w $$

Now factor out the 2 and 3 respectively from the last two equations:

$$ 0a + 3b + 7c + 11d = \;w\; $$

$$ 1a + 1b + 1c + 1d = x-w $$

$$ 1a + 1b + 1c + 1d = \frac{y-w}{2} $$

$$ 1a + 1b + 1c + 1d = \frac{z-w}{3} $$

We begin to see that these equations cannot always be solved, because the last three left hand sides will always be equal, but the values of $w,x,y,z$ may not give the last three right hand sides as equal!  Let's take the next step and subtract the second equation from the last two:

$$ 0a + 3b + 7c + 11d = \;w\; $$

$$ 1a + 1b + 1c + 1d = x-w $$

$$ 0a + 0b + 0c + 0d = \frac{y-w}{2} - (x-w) $$

$$ 0a + 0b + 0c + 0d = \frac{z-w}{3} - (x-w) $$

Can we always find a solution to these equations?  No, because we can pick values for $w,x,y,z$ that make the right hand sides in either of the last two equations *nonzero* while any choice of $a,b,c,d$ will only give a left hand side there of *zero*.  For example we might take $x=1$ and $w=y=z=0$, so the right hand sides of the last two equations are $-1$.  The system is then *inconsistent*, since $0 \neq -1$.

With a little thought we can also see that the four vectors (matrices) are not linearly independent.  That is some choice of $a,b,c,d$ other than simply $a=b=c=d=0$ will allow us to get all zeros on the right hand sides (since now $w=x=y=z=0$ is stipulated):

$$ 0a + 3b + 7c + 11d = 0 $$

$$ 1a + 1b + 1c + 1d = 0 $$

$$ 0a + 0b + 0c + 0d = 0 $$

$$ 0a + 0b + 0c + 0d = 0 $$

We really only have two equations (the first two of our last system) to determine four unknowns, and the Reader should be familiar with the fact that this is not possible for linear equations.  If a particular nontrivial choice of $a,b,c,d$ is desired, let $c=1$ and $d=0$ in the those two equations, and work out that $b=-\frac{7}{3}$ and $a=\frac{4}{3}$.  So $a=b=c=d=0$ is *not* the only way to express the zero 2x2 matrix as a linear combination of the four vectors.

Comment: The Reader who wishes to check for expressing as a linear combination a matrix that *is* in the span of these four matrices might look at $\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: I'm not really sure what that tells me... I was wondering this: does finding a particular solution for (x,y,z,w), in which there are no "rows of 0" indicate that it spans? or is that wrong? I'm wondering this for all basis of vector space Mmn problems.

Comment: Spanning means that you can find a solution for any $w,x,y,z$.  The comment above is a case for which a solution does exist (that matrix is "in the span" of the four matrices), and in my Answer was given a case where no solution exists ($x=1,w=y=z=0$) .

Comment: I see. thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

Algebraically, this is the same as showing that the vectors
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix},\ \begin{bmatrix}3\\4\\5\\6\end{bmatrix},\ \begin{bmatrix}7\\8\\9\\10\end{bmatrix},\ \begin{bmatrix}11\\12\\13\\14\end{bmatrix}
$$
(top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right) form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$.

(I will note, however, that as written: this is false. If the matrices are $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$ (respectively), then $x_1=4$, $x_2=1$, $x_3=-13$, and $x_4=8$ makes $\sum x_iA_i$ the $0$-matrix, for instance.)

Comment: I have a question just like this to solve and the books example is generalized and is very vague about how to solve a specific problem. but in it, it said u have to show that the trivial solution = 0 and to see if they form a basis you have to see if c1M1 +c2M2 + c3M3 + C4M4 = B, and it showed B being equal to |a,b,c,d| (2x2 matrix). but theres no c values or B so how can we apply that example? can anyone explain the whole process please?

Comment: could you elaborate a little more on your answer Nicholas? I find it hard to understand.

Comment: @jl You seem to have a new question; you should post it as one!

Comment: thank you hardmath, I was able to follow everything you wrote completey. I didn't know that I was supposed to expand it into a 4x4 system of equations. I can see how I'm supposed to find Linear Independence. just to make sure though, in order to see if the the matrices span, do you just have to find a particular solution that works, such as the arbitrary solution x1=9, x2=8, x3=−7, and x4=6 ?

Comment: I did Nicholas, and then it got marked a duplicate and down voted..